# Memory Compression R foreach loop

Tags: r, memory, foreach, parallel-processing, compression

I am using the `foreach` package and `doParallel` to subset (using `data.table`) 16 million rows and 5 columns 13 million times, according to a unique identifier. I have 32GB of RAM in total.

The process works fine if I break the loop up into iterations smaller than 250000 runs. Below this threshold, processing time is more or less linearly related.

However, when the parallel processing stops and `foreach` is (what I guess) stitching the results together, the system starts compressing memory. It specifically compresses the parallel instances of R and can grow up to 3GB at 1 million iterations.

I am currently running the loop in lots of 100000, and it takes approximately 12 minutes per lot. I ran it overnight in lots of 1 million and it took 9 hours per lot and the compressed memory process was 3GB (even though I had about 14GB overhead). The parallel instances of R themselves only were taking up about 60MB each, which is what leads me to think this is what is being compressed.

Compression only takes place after a length of time when the parallel instances of R are inactive and the loop is combining the results. At around 250000 lots, the time taken is 36 minutes but a lot of 500000 starts taking around 2 hours when the compressed memory process grows big enough.

The below picture illustrates the loop running as the processors kick in and garbage collection had taken place for iterations of 100000. At iterations of 50000 or less there is no compression element at all.

I have read you can disable this compression process by disabling page file altogether but it seems risky if I misestimate my peak RAM usage (peak at 100000 iterations is 80% memory usage). Does anyone know of a way to stop memory compression from compressing the parallel instances of R? I truly think it is causing the slowdown (from observing task manager (always) and experimentation) but I may be wrong also.

Code

```
start<-Sys.time()

cl<-makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

for(k in 13:130) {
write.csv(k,paste("E:/police/Loop/",k,".csv",sep=""))

matrix.fsl<-matrix(rep("NA", 100000*128), nrow = 100000, ncol = 128)


a<-100000*k-99999
b<-100000*k

matrix.fsl<-foreach(i=a:b,.combine=rbind, .packages = "data.table") %dopar% {  

temp<-FSL[Internal.CAS.Object.No==POLICE.FORENSICS.KEY[i,POLICE.FORENSICS.KEY]]
temp<-as.data.frame(temp)

#Labs
x1<-subset(temp,temp$Lab.Province==lab[1])
x2<-subset(temp,temp$Lab.Province==lab[2])
x3<-subset(temp,temp$Lab.Province==lab[3])
x4<-subset(temp,temp$Lab.Province==lab[4])
x5<-subset(temp,temp$Lab.Province==lab[5])

#exam type
for(j in 1:length(exam)) {
nam<-paste("y.",j,sep="")
temp2<-nrow(subset(temp,temp$Examination.Type==exam[j]))
assign(nam, temp2)

}

exam.temp<-c(y.1,y.2,y.3,y.4,y.5,y.6,y.7,y.8,y.9,y.10,y.11,y.12,y.13,y.14,y.15,y.16,
y.17,y.18,y.19,y.20,y.21,y.22,y.23,y.24,y.25,y.26,y.27,y.28,y.29,y.30,y.31,y.32,
y.33,y.34,y.35,y.36,y.37,y.38,y.39,y.40,y.41,y.42,y.43,y.44,y.45,y.46,y.47,y.48,
y.49,y.50,y.51,y.52,y.53,y.54,y.55,y.56,y.57,y.58,y.59,y.60,y.61,y.62,y.63,y.64,
y.65,y.66,y.67,y.68,y.69,y.70)

temp.police<-POLICE[INTERNAL_OBJECT_NUMBER==POLICE.FORENSICS.KEY[i,POLICE.FORENSICS.KEY]]
temp.police<-as.data.frame(temp.police)

#dssc
for(j in 1:length(dssc)) {
nam<-paste("y.",j,sep="")
temp2<-nrow(subset(temp.police,temp.police$DSSC_CODE_DESCRIPTION==dssc[j]))
assign(nam, temp2)

}

dssc.temp<-c(y.1,y.2,y.3,y.4,y.5,y.6,y.7,y.8,y.9,y.10,y.11)

#roh descr

for(j in 1:3) {
nam<-paste("y.",j,sep="")
temp2<-nrow(subset(temp.police,temp.police$CRIM_ROH_DESCR==crim[j]))
assign(nam, temp2)

}

crim.temp<-c(y.1,y.2,y.3)

#province
for(j in 1:length(prov)) {
nam<-paste("y.",j,sep="")
temp2<-nrow(subset(temp.police,temp.police$PROVINCE==prov[j]))
assign(nam, temp2)

}

prov.temp<-c(y.1,y.2,y.3,y.4,y.5,y.6,y.7,y.8,y.9)

#Year reported

for(j in 1:length(year.rep)) {
nam<-paste("y.",j,sep="")
temp2<-nrow(subset(temp.police,temp.police$YEAR_REPORTED==year.rep[j]))
assign(nam, temp2)

}

year.temp<-c(y.1,y.2,y.3,y.4,y.5,y.6,y.7,y.8,y.9,y.10,y.11,y.12,y.13)


#Month reported

for(j in 1:length(month.rep)) {
nam<-paste("y.",j,sep="")
temp2<-nrow(subset(temp.police,temp.police$MONTH_REPORTED==month.rep[j]))
assign(nam, temp2)

}

month.temp<-c(y.1,y.2,y.3,y.4,y.5,y.6,y.7,y.8,y.9,y.10,y.11,y.12)

#forensics

for(j in 1:length(forensics)) {
nam<-paste("y.",j,sep="")
temp2<-nrow(subset(temp.police,temp.police$Forensics==forensics[j]))
assign(nam, temp2)

}

forensics.temp<-c(y.1,y.2)

#court

for(j in 1:length(court)) {
nam<-paste("y.",j,sep="")
temp2<-nrow(subset(temp.police,temp.police$Court==court[j]))
assign(nam, temp2)

}

court.temp<-c(y.1,y.2)

y<-c(POLICE.FORENSICS.KEY[i],nrow(x1),nrow(x2),nrow(x3),nrow(x4),nrow(x5),
exam.temp, dssc.temp, crim.temp, prov.temp, year.temp, month.temp,
forensics.temp, court.temp)


y
}




write.csv(matrix.fsl,paste("E:/Police/Matrix/Matrix_",k,".csv",sep=""))
rm(matrix.fsl)
gc()


}

stopCluster(cl)
end<-Sys.time()
```

[Memory Compression Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xoa3X.jpg)

Comment: Where is your code? Most importantly, which function do you use for combining the results from the tasks?

Comment: Are you using `rbind` in your .combine argument? If so, that is likely (one of) your problem(s).

Comment: Hi, I am using rbind in the .combine argument. The essence of the code is

Comment: Hi, I am using rbind in the .combine argument. I will post the code when I get a chance but I just lost my teamviewer on my work computer. In essence I am just counting rows of subsets of the data. So subset by unique identier first. Then calculate other subsets for instance. In this context, counting the number of guilty, withdrawn etc verdicts, the number of forensics analyses run of each type etc per case at a national level. I've literally only used data.table subsets DT[,V1==criteria[i]), normal subset() for smaller subsets, nrow() to count and c() to combine all temporary variables.

Comment: Most likely your data.table code could be improved so much that you wouldn't need parallelization.

Comment: It's not too bad. It would take about 1.38 days and would give me a useful matrix. I'm open to using data.table to improve it though. If I don't parallelize, then I would have to watch TV instead of Task Manager, which is far less entertaining